# How to manage JavaScript scripts called from a Delphi application?

Tags: javascript, delphi, delphi-xe6

I have a program that leverages Google Maps from embedded JavaScript in Delphi (XE6).

I send it with `TWebBrowser`'s `HTMLWindow2.execScript` method. I have many external calls and call backs using COM.

The constant to house the JavaScript is over 400 lines and is becoming nearly unmanageable.  Since the JS is one string, the returned error offers little help.  Many times, I have searched for a typo of out of scope var for hours.

I do use another editor, JetBrains, for my raw JS and that helps, but now I have to spend most of my time in Delphi IDE, to do the External stuff.

I was wondering if there is a better way to manage the script in Delphi?

Comment: Can't you embed all your javascript on the page you are showing on TWebBrowser? This way you can test it on a regular webbrowser and only make specific calls from delphi.